# How to Expand volume /snap/

Tags: disk-usage

pls help expand /snap/core/
Which is 100% full. Or how to clear space?

Server hangs more often

I dont know how to proceed. 
Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu!  Snap apps are sandboxed so they always show 100% used.  Their settings and data are actually stored in your home user folder.   More than likely it is not snaps that are causing your hanging, but probably RAM and Swap space.   Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1226589/edit) your question and add more details like version of Ubuntu you are using.  Your system specs, like model of motherboard, amount of RAM installed, hard drive size.  Maybe also add the output of `df -h`.  The more details you add the better we can help you!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

R1: You can remove them with: *sudo snap remove core --revision  manually*
R2: you can expand it by expanding /var volume (where it is actually located  /var/lib/snapd/ ) or assigning more space on next installation.

The default in /snapd/core is to keep 3 versions of every snapd program, current and two previous, if you're seeing more than 3 then it's probably a bug ***but be careful, in a server snaps are so important as your services/apps because every snap is a full non-compressed filesystem for each snap including data+lib+config+services as an independent instance for compatibility/operational independence of OS's version***, so in case of installation/management (real) errors I'd file it at *bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd* . Would need to see the output of "snap changes" and show directory listing maybe in /snap/ to show multiple installed versions.

Multiple versions of snaps & garbage collection section in Snaps and snapcraft documentation explains that after every update of a snap package the current version and the one before are installed and older versions are getting automatically removed. So please keep an eye on your installations logs.

I hope this help you...

Taken from @cl-netbox and @popey: questions/895634/old-ubuntu-core-snap-versions-are-filling-up-disk-space
Edited: edited Mar 23 '17 at 15:11
and expanded with @dclinton: https://hackernoon.com/managing-ubuntu-snaps-the-stuff-no-one-tells-you-625dfbe4b26c

Comment: Expand your knowledge about... https://hackernoon.com/managing-ubuntu-snaps-the-stuff-no-one-tells-you-625dfbe4b26c

Comment: /snap/core is the virtual vol but the real (to expand) in use by active snaps is /var/lib/snapd/ having in mind that a snap is really a single "non compressed+non installed" file with .snap extension, containing the entire file system needed for running a package mounted dynamically at run time and exposed to the user as a virtual. This means that the resources used by a program might not actually exist on the host system.